# How to list all users that have a specific Temporary Tablespace like as default

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I'd like how list all users that have a specific Temporary Tablespace Default.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a select on **dba_users**

Example

```
select a.USERNAME
from dba_users a
Where 
  TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE = '<NAME TEMP TABLESPACE>';
```